# Commerce Paypal Payment Standard Currency Conversion

Tags: 7, commerce, payment-gateways

I have integrated paypal payment standard using commerce paypal module in my website. I have 2 currencies my default currency is AED. Now I have 1500 AED in a cart When I am proceeding to checkout on paypal its showing 1500 USD. Isn't it possible that the amount converts in equivalent USD automatically ??

Comment: It sounds like this is a feature request for the [Commerce PayPal](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) module so should be posted in their [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_paypal?categories=All).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PayPal Payments Standard module only supports the currencies PayPal specifically identifies in its API documentation as supported currencies. When it encounters an unsupported currency, it converts it to whatever currency you have set as the default currency in the configuration of the related payment method rule. Since the default conversion rate is 1:1, that's why this is being passed to PayPal as 1500 USD.

I don't know to what extent PayPal supports the Dirham. If your account does, then it could be you need to patch the PayPal module to support payment transactions in AED. Otherwise you're going to need to use the Commerce Multicurrency module to set an actual conversion rate between the AED and the PayPal supported currency you want to receive payment / maintain a balance in.

Comment: Thank You Ryan. I have used this multicurrency module which worked for me the way it was required. But the automatic currency exchange rates are not working for my currency, is there any other currency conversion service we can use instead of European Central Bank

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. I haven't used the module, but you might try a support request directly in its issue queue.

Answer (score 2):

I done this successfully, you have to follow these steps

In Currency settings go to Currency conversion then select Synchronize rates on save. Then check the option "Synchronize all rates of this currency" below at your own currency. Then unchecked the option "Synchronize this conversion rate" below at USD and save settings.

after that add product to your cart and continue to checkout you will find appropriate converted currency in Paypal payment form.

Comment: I am using pound, I need its conversion rates automatically, I did this all. But the conversion rates vary often, In such case do we need to run a cron or something?

Comment: this does not make sense .